# Drupal 7 forums migration (import and add new forums in addition to the existing ones)

Tags: drupal, migration

What is the best and nicest way of exporting all the forums and all their content from one **Drupal 7** site and importing it into another **existing** Drupal 7 site ?

The destination site already has other forums, topics and comments.
So I need to be able to import and add new forums, in addition to the existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Node Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) module to get the content out of the current site and into the new site. You would need to install the module on both sites. Depending on the size of the export, you could do something as simple as VBO to export your content then import into the new site using the Import tab (provided by Node Export) on the content creation tab. You could get as complex as using Feeds or Features to handle your data migration. Can you tell us about how many posts you are talking about?

If you have the same content types across sites, things are easier. If not you would need to use Feeds to map the fields from site to site, or use Features to create new content types on the destination server (or do it manually if you like).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  There are no new content types.  It's just forum topics and their comments.  I am talking about ~ 350 topics ~1000 forum topic comments (each comment belongs to a forum topic).

Comment: One more thing : It seems that "Node Export" exports only the node and not its comments.

Comment: I managed to perform bulk export today with VBO, but as I wrote, "Node Export" exports only the node and not its comments. - I am looking for a whole solution. Any idea how I can do that (export all the forums topics and their comments ?

Answer (score 0):

There's already a release of Drupal 9, here you can read how to migrate to the latest version https://anyforsoft.com/blog/drupal-9-release/

Comment: Its better to explain your solutions here.